# Why do I get wrong normal map?

Tags: baking, normal-map

td;tr I'm trying to do my hello-world with creating my own normal maps. I've took this [40-second lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LuEqvO9QsE). I'm doing exactly as in the tutorial. This is my "low-poly" cube.

[image: low-poly]

This is my "high-poly" cube.

[image: high-poly]

Node setup

[image: node setup]

And selection during baking, just in case.

[image: selection]

But instead of correct normal map I get this weirdness.

[image: normal map]

Can anybody explain why this happens, please.

Comment: Hello :). That's because your faces are flat or vertical. Normal maps don't bake height differences, but face direction. Add some bevel to your edges and it should work.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.